# Earth Engine Python API set system:id property with function

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I want to change the `system:id` of images in an image collection based on the `system:index`.  I can do this in the javascript api like this:

```js
//read in image collection
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA");

//get first two images
var first_two = l8.limit(2)

//print system:index with slice for first image
var idx = ee.String(first_two.first().get('system:index')).slice(0,4)

print(idx)

//set system id with function
var repls = function(feature){
  var sub =  ee.String(feature.get('system:index')).slice(0,4);
  return(feature.set('system:id', sub))
};


//apply function
first_two = first_two.map(repls)

print(first_two)
```

Here is a runnable script:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/7452dbd8307d04ab17e4dc262b0554c2

This works just fine, but I want to do the same thing in python.  I am doing it like this:

```py
#read in image collection
l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA")

#get first two images
first_two = l8.limit(2)

#print system:index with slice for first one
idx = str(first_two.first().get('system:index').getInfo())[0:4]

print(idx)

#set system id in loop
def repls(feature):
  sub = feature.get('system:index').getInfo()[0:4]
  return feature.set('system:id', sub)

#map the function
l8 = l8.map(repls)

print(l8)
```

but this fails with:

`EEException: A mapped function's arguments cannot be used in client-side operations`

This only fails when applying the function to an image collection.  For instance, I have no problem in python doing this to a single image:

```py
l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA")
    
first = l8.first()
    
#print system:index with slice
idx = str(first.get('system:index').getInfo())[0:4]
    
print(idx)
    
#set system id
first = first.set('system:id', idx)
    
print(first.get('system:id').getInfo())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getInfo()` is a client-side operation and cannot be used in `map()`. Likewise, Python list subsetting `[0:4]` cannot be used inside `map()` either.

Instead, you can use the server-side [`slice`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-string-slice) to substring the `'system:index'`, just like you do in javascript:

```py
#set system id in loop
def repls(feature):
  # cast the 'system:index' as an ee.String and slice the first 4 characters
  sub = ee.String(feature.get('system:index')).slice(0,4)
  return feature.set('system:id', sub)

#map the function
l8 = l8.map(repls)

# printing the whole collection resulted in too many elements, so print the first image
print(l8.first().getInfo())
```